# Selecting element using webdriver (duplicate identifiers)

Tags: webdriver-io

I have to look at an application which I can't use the normal selectors (like "id", "name", etc - this is a design flaw) but I do have a custom tag which has been applied to elements on the page:

```
test-tag='x'
```

and this is fine, I can interact with this using (simple script)

```
var tag = '[test-tag="x"]';
var selector = $(tag);
```

However, I have now found that some elements (notably textboxes) have a title and a box element - both have the same custom tag applied.  Now the text box is an input type.  Anyone know how I can change the above to target specifially input types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
'input[test-tag="x"]'
```

for the input box

Take a look at this as well:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Shanoor - I am sure I had tried this and it didn't work - but this time it did.  Many thanks